# GEE: How to calculate mean of specific images each year in image collection (NASA NEX-GDDP climate model)?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, climate

Google Earth Engine: I am trying to calculate some climatic projections for Ukraine from NASA NEX-GDDP data. This is the [dataset I am using](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_NEX-GDDP#image-properties). I am using the min temperature ("tasmin") band. The image collection contains images for many different climate models from 1950 to 2099 and for both rcp45 and rcp85 scenarios.

I would like to calculate the average "tasmin" value of all models in scenario rcp45 for every pixel in Ukraine across the whole 2010 to 2020 period. Please could you let me know how I can adapt [this code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0d341c9fa34e4977e7d1b46ebc035a5a) to calculate this?